# Como recuperar datos especificos en una API REST NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Estoy intentando recuperar los datos de un usuario especifico, pero sin los datos que crea `MongoDB Atlas` por defecto. Me explico.

Cuando utilizo el verbo `GET`, recupero el siguiente `JSON`:

```
  {
        "_id": "63d06a33030adfdce00668b6",
        "id": 1,
        "email": "dev@company.com",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "company": "Google",
        "text": "A personal description",
        "__v": 0
   }
```

Pero me gustaria recibir solamente

```
  {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "dev@company.com",
        "first_name": "John",
        "last_name": "Smith",
        "company": "Google",
        "text": "A personal description"
   }
```

Como puedo hacerlo?

Ésta es mi funcion GetUser:

```
 function GetUser(req, res){
    const { id } = req.params;
    userSchema
        .find({id})
        .then((data) => res.json(data))
        .catch((error) => res.json({msg: error }))
};
```

Intenté de esta manera pero no funcionó... qué otra manera puedo hacerlo? Hay alguna configuracion en `MongoDB Atlas` para ésto?

```
const { email, first_name, last_name, company, url, text } = req.body
    userSchema
        .find({ id: id }, { $get: { email, first_name, last_name, company, url, text } })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar obtener la data de esta forma:

```
userSchema.find({}, {_id:0});
```

Ahí lo que hace es obtener todos los campos de tu tabla user a excepción del campo "_id".

Comment: Gracias!!!! Eso me ayudo muchisimo...